# Is this recursive function iterative?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, scheme

I'm watching the sicp lectures, In video 1b, sussman calls algo 1 iterative. He says method 2 is recursive. From my understanding both are recursive algorithms. How can I best think of method 1? As an iterative recursive algo?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlbMuv-jix8

method 1 - time complexity is o(x), space is o(1)

```
 (define (+ x y)
        (if (= x 0)
            y
            (+ (-1+ x) (1+ y))))
```

method 2 - time complement is o(x), space is o(x)

```
(define (+ x y)
    (if (= x 0)
        y
        (1+ (+ (-1+ x) y))))
```

Comment: The book is very good, is available online, and has a [pretty good discussion](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2) of what a recursive *procedure* implementing an iterative *process* means in SICP. You can also find (legal!) ebook and pdf versions of the book online.

Comment: Thank you! The discussion link drives the point home. I just implemented an iterative version of factorial.

Answer (score 1):

Both are recursive, but some languages, like Scheme, require that implementations perform  [tail call elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) on the first example. A **tail-recursive** subroutine is one that calls itself *last* in the control flow. These subroutines can be reorganized by the interpreter/compiler so that they are performed iteratively to save stack space.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is tail recursive, thus iterative, and the second grows the stack and is not.

In the SICP videos they call tail recursive procedures iterative. They tend to call the non iterative procedures just recursive even though recursion is the only loop mechanism in Scheme. (Things like `do` is just syntactic sugar for a tail recursive procedure call.)
There isn't a good name for the opposite of tail recursive procedures.

Still, Sussman is both one of the authors of Scheme and one of the author of SICP book so of all the wizards he's the greatest. The video is from the 80s and the report at the time was R3RS. Even if the language they're using is an old version of Scheme it's not far from the most used scheme report today, R5RS.

Answer (score 0):

The first algorithm is recursive in how it is expressed, but note that it is *tail recursion* (also called a [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call))—the recursive call is the last thing in the algorithm. Tail recursion is trivially transformed into iteration. In the second algorithm, the recursive call is used to evaluate one of the arguments, hence is not tail recursion.

I haven't bothered to watch the video, but I imagine that's why the first algorithm is described as iterative.